# Idea about syzygy

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am studying commutative algebra by myself. I got stuck to understand some concepts like syzygy. I am looking for a good reference for that even if it is a paper.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I always thought "syzygy" was a purely Astronomical term. Learn something new every day. :)

Comment: You can look at the book *"The Geometry of Syzygies: A Second Course in Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry"* by David Eisenbud.

Comment: Another source http://www.ams.org/notices/200604/what-is.pdf

Comment: Some semantics here for "syzygy" (Wikipedia: "Linear Relation"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_relation

Answer (score -1):

I encountered Syzygy in N-body problem, so I'm not sure if it'd be a help, but Richard Montgomery has used this concept in his papers with some explanations. take a look at: https://people.ucsc.edu/~rmont/papers/list.html
(crtl/command+f) syzygy.